# Issue with loading an eps file into a document

Tags: eps, texworks, epstopdf

I'm having issue getting latex (Texworks on windows) to read in an eps file. I have had it working exactly as below before on an installation on  different PC. Now I have installed tex and the interpreter on my laptop and the below no longer works. The error is related to some sort of draft setting:

```
! Package pdftex.def Error: File `figures/TestingRecordedSignals_TEST-eps-conve
rted-to.pdf' not found: using draft setting.
```

Anyone seen this before and have any suggestions?

```
\documentclass[superscriptaddress,aps,preprint,amsmath,amssymb,prb,floatfix,nobibnotes,10pt]{revtex4}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics{figures/TestingRecordedSignals_TEST.eps}
\caption{Voltage Signals recorded during Wind Tunnel Testing}
\label{fig:PressureSignals}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you provide a download to the `.eps` file using Google Docs, Dropbox, or any other file sharing service? That way we can run the example code your provided. Which will hopefully help with finding the answer.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ixbsh3lzkuegkeu/TestingRecordedSignals_TEST.eps?dl=0

Comment: There's a link to the file.

Comment: The document works fine on my installation. I get this error message only if there is no subdirectory `figure` or if this directory does not contain `TestingRecordedSignals_TEST.eps`. Check whether the `eps` file is where LaTeX is looking for it.

Comment: do you have ghostscript installed  on your machine?

Answer (score 1):

The `draft` mode is a fallback because the figure is not found.
The missing `TestingRecordedSignals_TEST-eps-converted-to.pdf` is the pdf files suposed to be prodiced automatically, at compile time, by the package `epspdf` you loaded.

Are you sure that your `.eps` is actually in the "figure" subdirectory of the main folder, that is to say the folder containing your LaTeX file ?

I can't reproduce your error. Perhaps you could try:

- to put the `.eps` in the main directory
- or to convert the file "by hand" using `ghostscript` or `ghostview` or the `ps2psf.exe` utility provided by MikTeX with a command line like :

  `"C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\ps2pdf.exe" TestingRecordedSignals_TEST.eps TestingRecordedSignals_TEST.pdf`

and then calling `\includegraphics` without extension:

```
\includegraphics{figures/TestingRecordedSignals_TEST}
```

Off-topic : there is no need of `[H]` here and hence not need for `float`.

**Edit:** (minimal) command to use wit `ghostscript`:

```
"C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.18\bin\gswin64c.exe"  -dEPSCrop -sDEVICE=pdfwrite  -o TestingRecorded.pdf TestingRecorded.eps
```

where the path to `gswin64c.exe` should be adapted to your installation.

Comment: I tried putting it in the main directory and still the same error. I've downloaded ghostscript now but haven't figured out how to use it yet.

Comment: Is there a simple way to test eps2pdf is working outside of latex? As that seems to be the issue.

Comment: Fot ghostscript, see the edit in my answer.

Comment: Ok so I tested just using eps2pdf directly in command prompt (understood how that works more than gs tbh) and that worked fine. Placing the new pdf in the figure folder also worked fine when i remove the .eps at the end of it. Any suggestions as to how to get this to work in latex given that its definitely in the correct location and the epstopdf application works fine by itself?

Comment: eps2pdf is an utility based on ghostscript and TTBOMK it has nothing to do with the ``epspdf`` package.  So yout diagnostic is is not correct. Is your MikTeX up to date?

Comment: Apologies I meant to say epstopdf in the earlier comment (the package used by latex) I tested that from the texlive distribution and it worked, is MikTeX a better option to try?

Comment: Apolofize too. I had the false impression that you were using MikTeX. There a some reasons to prefer MiKTeK  on a Windows PC, but if you are used to TeXLive, don't change. Both distributions come with an  embedded ghostscript library. Some ancillary programs, including the``epstopdf``/utility/ which is a perl script, and in MikTeX a self contained exe, as Windows PC usually don't have perl. The epstopdf /package/  calls this utility from within ``pdflatex``.
**To have it working, you must enable the shell-escape feature of your tex engine with ``--shell-escape`` or ``--enable-write18``.**

Comment: So if I understood correctly, I need to enable "--shell-escape" in my typeset in texworks? I have tried this (see text below) and it didn't do any good, I am getting the same error.                                                             $synctexoption -- shell-escape $fullname

Comment: Try on the command line ``pdflatex --shell-escape yourtexfile``, or have a look on my ``texworks`` configuration (for MikTeX): 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/nf8n2bfgbzjplap/texworks-config.png

Comment: Just tried both of these suggestions, both returned the same error as before. Think it's worth installing MikTeX and trying that to see if that somehow fixes it (no idea why it should but out of other ideas)